Distributing row height when cells span rows in tblr environment
Is there any way to evenly distribute the height of rows participating in a span set?
For example, the row with the column A value of val2 is taller than the preceding rows two rows:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{ipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[1,c,m]Q[4.5,l,m]Q[3.5,l,m]Q[5,l,m]},
    width = \linewidth,
    hlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
    vlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
    vline{2-4} = {1,Z}{white,solid,0.4pt},
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white}
  }
  A & B & C & D \\
  val0 & \SetCell[r=3]{} {value 0\\value 1\\value 2\\value 3\\value 4\\value 5} & \SetCell[r=3]{} lorem & value \\*
  val1 & & & value \\*
  val2 & & & value \\
  val0 & \SetCell[r=3]{} {value 0} & \SetCell[r=3]{} lorem & value \\*
  val1 & & & value \\*
  val2 & & & value \\
  A & B & C & D
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}



You could use the vspan=even option to distribute the row heights evenly:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{ipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
    colspec = {Q[1,c,m]Q[4.5,l,m]Q[3.5,l,m]Q[5,l,m]},
    width = \linewidth,
    hlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
    vlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
    vline{2-4} = {1,Z}{white,solid,0.4pt},
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
    vspan=even
  }
  A & B & C & D \\
  val0 & \SetCell[r=3]{} {value 0\\value 1\\value 2\\value 3\\value 4\\value 5} & \SetCell[r=3]{} lorem & value \\*
  val1 & & & value \\*
  val2 & & & value \\
  val0 & \SetCell[r=3]{} {value 0} & \SetCell[r=3]{} lorem & value \\*
  val1 & & & value \\*
  val2 & & & value \\
  A & B & C & D
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


